# How to remove big blank space on my list pagination [SwiftUI]

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI  and I trying to remove the blank space on my list pagination. Everytime when the list loaded the new page, a blank space is pop-up. how can I fix this?

You can see the problem by bellow attached image,
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhIWA.jpg)

this is my list view

## My List

```
                   List {
                                LazyVGrid(columns: setGridLayout(), spacing: 20) {
                                    ForEach(viewModel.personPopularList, id: \.id) { person in
                                        PeopleCardView(person: person)
                                            .listRowBackground(Color.white)
                                            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                                    }
                                    .id(UUID())
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                                }
                                .listRowBackground(Color.white)
                                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                            }
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .onAppear(perform: {
                                   UITableView.appearance().contentInset.top = -20
                                   UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                               })
                            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
```

this is my cardview

## My CardView

```
struct PeopleCardView: View {

@State var person: PersonPopularResult

var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .center) {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            WebImage(url: URL(string: Constant.POSTER_URL + (person.profilePath ?? "")))
                .placeholder {
                    Image("placeholder")
                }
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .stroke(Color.mPurple, lineWidth: 3))
            Spacer()
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("\(person.name!)")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .font(.system(size: 21))
                    .font(.headline)
                Text("Popolarity Rate: \(String(format: "%.3f", person.popularity!))")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(.mPurple)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .padding(.top, -8)
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding([.top, .leading], 10)
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 100, alignment: .center)
        .padding()
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15, style: .continuous)
                .fill(.white)
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .stroke(Color.mPurple, lineWidth: 3))
                .shadow(radius: 7)
        )
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
}
```

}

thanks for anyone can help to my problem.

Comment: It's very unusual to put `LazyVGrid` inside a `List` -- maybe you want a `ScrollView`? `.id(UUID())` is an anti pattern -- it'll enforce that the view gets completely recreated on each render, breaking SwiftUI's diffing mechanism. Besides that, this needs a [mre] to be debugged further.

Comment: its working properly now. thanks for your advice.